# Can csv-conduit read a string in csv form and parse it into some intermediate datatype?

Tags: parsing, csv, haskell, conduit

The documentation found on csv-conduit's github page is scant, my use case involve reading a string in csv form, ie:

```
csv :: String
csv = "\"column1 (text)\",\"column2 (text)\",\"column3 (number)\",\"column4 (number)\"\r\anId,stuff,12,30.454\r\n"
```

and transforming it into some intermediate data type, so suppose we declare data type `Row`, then I'd have

```
csv' :: Row
csv' = Row (Just "anId") "stuff" 12 (Just 30.454)
```

But I'm not sure which functions to call. Furthermore, it seems like csv-conduit export some `Row` type already, but I'm not sure how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which shows how to add a processing step in a cvs conduit pipeline. Here we just add a column to each input row.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib
where

import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary
import Data.CSV.Conduit
import Data.Text
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad

myProcessor :: Monad m => Conduit (MapRow Text) m (MapRow Text)
myProcessor = do
  x <- await
  case x of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just m -> do let m' = Map.insert "asd" "qwe" m
                 yield m'
                 myProcessor

test = runResourceT $
   sourceFile "input.csv" $=
   intoCSV defCSVSettings $=
   myProcessor $=
   (writeHeaders defCSVSettings >> fromCSV defCSVSettings) $$
   sinkFile "output.csv"
```

Of course, your processing stage doesn't have to produce `MapRow Text` items - it can produce items of whatever type you want. Use other conduit operations to collect / filter / process that pipeline.

If you have a specific task you want to perform I can address that.